# Como identificar instancias repetidas?

Tags: javascript

```js
function Cell(){
  
  this.id = null;  
  this.name = "";
  
}
var x = [1,4,5,9,17,25,254,4];
var i = 0;
var l = x.length;
for(;i<l;i++) {
  
  var b = new Cell();
  b.id = x[i];

 
  console.log(b.id);
}
```

Tengo un constructor `Cell()`, un array llamado `x`(con identificadores para Cell), y un ciclo `for` que crea instancias del constructor con la propiedad `id`, asignada ***desde los valores del*** array `x`.

¿Como puedo ***comprobar*** si hay `'this.id'` ***repetidas***? ya que por cada propiedad `'this.id'` ***quiero realizar una determinada*** `funcion` **pero** si la propiedad `'this.id'` *se repite*(en este caso se repite la id 4) , ***la funcion solo se aplica a la ultima de sus repeticiones, osea al ultimo 4***

***El problema no puedo resolverlo modificando el array y siempre con el mismo nombre de variable***

Algo similar a hacerlo con un array, pero ahora con las intancias

Ejemplo:

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,1]
var b = new Set()
a.reverse().forEach(x => b.add(x))
c = Array.from(b).reverse()

console.log(c);
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que primeramente para cada instancia de C la asignes a una variable diferente, en ves de estar sobre escribiendo la misma `b`, y de esa forma ya tienes identificado que valor tendrá `this.id` dependiendo de a que variable estés mandando llamar su atributo.

Comment: Lixus necesito hacerlo con el mismo nombre

Comment: Si te dijeran "Encuentra el último 4 de este array" ¿cómo lo harías?

Comment: Intenta guardar en otro atributo el índice del arreglo para así llevar un control de dónde provienen las instancias

Comment: Como es eso? podrias darme ejemplos con respuestas si es posible? por favor. Y he editado con un ejemplo en un array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al momento que seteas `b.id = x[i]` puedes chequear si es la última ocurrencia del valor `x[i]` dentro del array.

Para resolver eso puedes utilizar [Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/lastIndexOf), ya que esta función retorna el índice de la última ocurrencia del valor, pudiendo luego utilizar ese índice para verificar si coincide con tu variable de iteración `i`.

Si coincide sabes que te encuentras posicionado en la última ocurrencia, por ende invocarías la función que mencionas.

Si no coincide puede significar que hay un valor posterior (`index > i`) o que hay un valor anterior y el `id` fue utilizado (`index < i`) .

```js
function Cell(){
  this.id = null;  
  this.name = "";
}

var x = [1,4,5,9,17,25,254,4,88,17];
var i = 0;
var l = x.length;

for(;i<l;i++) {
  var b = new Cell();
  var index = x.lastIndexOf(x[i]);
  b.id = x[i];
  if(index !== i){
      console.log(b.id+ " Fue utilizado previamente o no es la ultima ocurrencia");
  }else{
      console.log(b.id+ " Es la ultima ocurrencia, invocar funcion..");
  }
 }
```